# How do I search for a partial word in a CloudKit record?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to search for CloudKit records containing search text entered by my users.

I have records with these titles (in String format):

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Test 1
- Test 2

I have tried using 'contains':

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains %@", searchText) 
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ShareableItem", predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { results, error in
    ...
```

But this only returns the results I'm looking for if I use a complete word as a search term.

EG. If I search for 'Item', I get back Item 1,Item 2 and Item 3 but if I search for 'tem' I don't get any results.

Is there a way of including a wildcard character in the search or another way of using partial search text?

I've also tried:

```
NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", searchText)
```

but with the same result

Comment: Looks correct to me. Have you checked the `searchText` for any leading or trailing spaces? Second, you might consider changing the column name away from `self` which might collide with the reserved word of Swift. And third thing you might want to try is, to use the like-syntax `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K like *%@*", ">>your column name<<", searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))`

Comment: Yep checked for spaces thanks. 'Self' isn't the column name it's a key path, part of the [CKQuery spec](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquery)  "The self key path causes the server to look in searchable string-based fields for the specified token string. For example, a predicate string of @"self contains 'blue'" searches for the word “blue” in all fields marked for inclusion in full-text searches.". Unfortunately like isn't supported in the CloudKit framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only search for partial texts in from the beginning of a field. For instance you could use:

```
NSPredicate(format: "YourTextField BEGINSWITH %@", searchText)
```

The token matches query searches for tokens (words) in your record. It will always search for complete words. So far I have only found one workaround for this issue and that is that you take the field where you want to search in en generate an extra field with all the partial tokens that you can generate. For instance if you have a field that contains the text `search text` then you will generate your tokens field containing `s se sea sear searc e ea ear earc earch a ar arc arch r rc rch c ch t te tex e ex ext x xt`. These will then all be treated as separate tokens.

Comment: Ouch. I worried that might be the case. Thanks. That workaround might be do-able as my text fields are short.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this has to do with indexes. Otherwise you would need a full table scan

Comment: I thought of another workaround. I could download all of the text fields, perform filtering locally, then fetch full records corresponding to the filtered local indices. Slightly ugly but allows better control of the filtering. I'll post when I've got it working.

Comment: @Derek That would only work when the number of records is not too large. The bennefit of that would be that you only need to do 1 request for the entire list and the response to the typing will be fast.